Selenium ChromeDriver: File not downloading after clicking the download button
I am trying to automate a file download process using Selenium with ChromeDriver, but the file is not being downloaded to the specified directory.
Issue: The program runs without any errors, but the file is not being downloaded to the C:/Users/timit/Downloads directory. I verified that the button click is working as expected.
Here is the code I am using:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import os  # For environment variables

# Chrome setup for file download
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")  # Profile path
chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=ProfileName")  # Profile name
prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": "C:/Users/YourUser/Downloads",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True
}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

# Login details (not included in this snippet)
client_code = os.getenv('CLIENT_CODE', 'YourClientCode')  
username = os.getenv('USERNAME', 'YourUsername')
password = os.getenv('PASSWORD', 'YourPassword')

# Navigate to login page
driver.get('https://login.tharanis.hu/belep.php')

# Login steps
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ukod"]').send_keys(client_code)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="username"]').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="okb"]').click()
time.sleep(5)

# Navigate through menu and click download
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="menu_main"]/li[3]'))
).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="menu_aruforgalom"]/li[3]/ul/li[1]/a'))
).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rakkeszw_footer"]/table/tbody/tr/td/input'))
).click()

# Wait for the download to complete
time.sleep(10)

driver.quit()

What I've Tried:
Confirmed that the download directory is correctly set in prefs.
Checked the browser settings to ensure downloads don’t require confirmation.
Used a fresh ChromeDriver installation.
Questions:
What could be causing the file not to download?
Are there additional browser or Selenium settings I should configure?
Could this issue be related to server-side prompts or authentication?
Any help would be appreciated!

"C:/Users/YourUser/Downloads" is not correct.  If you give it an incorrect path, it'll go back to default dir.  I'd use File.Separator for the "" just so it works on any OS, and you won't have to escape anything.  So something like:  System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+ "Downloads" + File.separator....  It'll also help to check that path and permissions beforehand... and create the dir and permissions if they don't exist.

When using Selenium and ChromeDriver to automate file downloads, if the file is not downloaded to the specified directory, first make sure that the download path is set correctly in the Selenium script via ChromeOptions.Check that the download settings of the Chrome browser allow automatic downloads.If the problem persists, try looking at the log output of ChromeDriver or consider using a different method to download the file.

I have the same problem: Chrome Selenium show file downloaded but I can't find it or click the file in download panel, works with firefox, so I use that instead. Firefox is more w3c compliant.

Thank you! I was also thinking about trying that route, but didn't want to believe Chromium can have such an issue :(
I will give Firefox a go!
